# Radio buttons in one line with values using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to ruby on rails. I am trying to create a page which will be like below

1. Criteria 1    1 O   2 O   3 O
2. Criteria 2    1 O   2 O   3 O

where **O-** is radio button

User can select only  1 value for each criteria.

I have  controller like below. I am not able to proceed

```
class JudgeController < ApplicationController
  def new
    # ..
  end
end
```

And a view `jude.html.erb`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's definitely more setting up you will have to do, but I'll make some assumptions and show you how you can create radio buttons.

```
<input id="critera_one" name="criteria" type="radio" value="1" />
<label for="critera_one">1</label>
<input id="critera_two" name="criteria" type="radio" value="2" />
<label for="critera_two">2</label>
```

You'll want to put something like this in your `judge.html.erb` file. This will create the radio buttons you need, and then you can access them in your controller. If you need help with that feel free to ask, but there's lots of available texts on how to do this that are pretty readily available. A good start for reading would be the Rails documentation for form helpers:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Also, in your question you have your file named `jude.html.erb`. I believe that's a typo, but if not you may want to spell it correctly in your app.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Will look into the documentation